gemini pro vision error 403 streamlit cloud
I made an application using Gemini pro Vision on python. using streamlit the local host is working fine. However after I deplyed my app to streamlit cloud the following error is showing:
PermissionDenied: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied:
[reason:
"ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
key: "service"
value: "generativelanguage.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
key: "method"
value: "google.ai.generativelanguage.v1beta.GenerativeService.GenerateContent"
}
]
I enabled the API with google cloud console but no changes.
its an app that takes photo and classify it with gemini

Can you please share the part of the code which triggers the error above?

Your error looks like an IAM/Access Issue.
In you local, when you https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login you skip a lot of IAM restrictions. When hosting an application need understanding what program is where and what permission does it have.
Not a perfect match but I suggest to look into following post to learn requirements about hosting an application and try again.

https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-build-a-chat-web-application-with-streamlit-cloud-run-and-gemini-flash-8eb1ac55b201

